Density of a subset of Schwartz space in the p-fractional Sobolev space
It is known that the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is dense in the fractional Sobolev space $W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ ($0<s<1$ and $1<p<\infty$) defined as
$$
W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^N) := \left\{ u \in L^p(R^N) : [u]_{s,p}< \infty \right\},
$$
endowed with the norm $\|u\|_{W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)} = \left( \| u \|^p_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)} + [u]_{s,p}^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$, where $[\cdot]_{s,p}$ is the Gagliardo seminorm defined as
$$
[u]_{s,p}:= \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \frac{|u(x) - u(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{N+sp}} {\rm d}x {\rm d}y \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}.
$$
Note that $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N) \subset \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and  $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is dense in $W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$.
Consider the following subset of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N)$:
$$ \mathcal{A} := \left\{ f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N) : \mathcal{F}(f) \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N \setminus \{ 0\}) \right\}. $$
Can we show that $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ (where $\mathcal{F}(f)$ is the Fourier transformation of $f$)?
Observe that, $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is not contained in $\mathcal{A}$. Because of this observation, the density won't follow using the density of $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$.
For $p=2$, this density result holds (see).

What is the definition of fractional Sobolev space you are using? For $p\neq 2$ there are at least two different commonly used spaces.

I have added the definition of W^{s,p}(R^N).

I don't know where I read it, and I could be very wrong, but I vaguely remember that these fractional Sobolev spaces can be written equivalently as a Besov space, I think $B^{s}_{p,p}(\mathbb R^n)$. The Besov space norm involves the Fourier transform, and it most likely solves the problem with little effort. Maybe you can try to look for this equivalent characterization in the series of books of Hans Triebel "Theory of function spaces". Probably the first book has something about that.
